# Can I decrypt only part of file encrypted with AES/CBC in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

How would I go about this? I have code encrypting a file using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Java and as I understand form this picture: [image]

Partial decryption should be possible having part of ciphertext used by preceding block and the key. I have not found any examples of this, though. Any help?

The decrypting code is as fallows:

```
    //skip the IV (ivSize is 16 here) - IV was pretended to the stream during encryption
    data.skip(ivSize);
    //skip n blocks
    int n = 2;
    System.out.println("skipped: " + data.skip(n*16));

    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    //use next 16 bytes as IV
    data.read(iv);

    // Hashing key.
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(encryptionKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(data, cipher);
    try {
        ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.limit(cis, limit), output);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        // starting with java 8 the JVM wraps an IOException around a GeneralSecurityException
        // it should be safe to swallow a GeneralSecurityException
        if (!(exception.getCause() instanceof GeneralSecurityException)) {
            throw exception;
        }
        log.warning(exception.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cis.close();
    }
```

Comment: according the diagram you could use the previous ciphertext as IV of the block you intend to decipher

Comment: yes, I tried but got javax.crypto.BadPaddingException - skipped couple 16 byte blocks and used the following block as IV

Comment: It decrypts but I get the above exception in the end.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As stated in the answer, Padding must **only be used for the last block of the entire encrypted message**, for all other blocks use no padding. `Cipher` must be instantiated with the correct padding option depending if it is the last block of the entire encrypted data or not

Comment: I have found working solutions https://gist.github.com/itarato/abef95871756970a9dad and http://www.itcsolutions.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/BouncyCastleProvider_AES_CBC.java.txt that can be used to implement this.

Comment: Grabbing something from GitHub is not understanding the problem/solution and just a short term fix.

Comment: @zaph Is it possible to decrypt a small part of a block? If a block has 16 bytes and I want to decrypt only the bytes between 4 and 10, i.e starting at 4º byte and ending at 10º byte. I'm doing padding start and padding end to the block to keep block size multiple but I get a weird output and not the decrypted part of plaintext itself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

You need to choose the "part" on a block boundary, a length that is a block size multiple and use the previous block as the IV. For AES the block size is 16-bytes.

If the "part" includes the last block specify the correct padding, otherwise specify no padding `NoPadding`: `AES/CBC/NoPadding` in this instance. This will eliminate a padding error. Only there last block is has/is padding.

`Cipher` must be instantiated with the correct padding option depending if it is the last block of the entire encrypted data or not.

See: [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) (sometimes called PKCS#5 in error) which is the most common padding.

Comment: Yes, in Java they decided to stay with "PKCS#5" even though PKCS#7 is used anyway...

Comment: Clarifying: It was just the Java developers being lazy with naming, it is really PKCS#7, by definition PKCS#5 only supports 8-byte block sizes. From the answer link: "*PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8-byte) block size. In practice the two can be used interchangeably.*"